# Free Barcode 128 library for C#

Tags: c#, barcode

Could anybody recommend a free barcode 128 library for C#? Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Sergejus. try the barcode for a test: http://freebarcode.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/GenCode128.aspx

Comment: There is no optimization for numeric-only output, so called set C. Barcodes with numbers only are going to be 2x wider

Comment: I'm the author of that library. Thanks for the plug.

Comment: @chriswuestefeld It is not working upto two digit strings. For example, the program terminates when i try to generate barcode of "4" or "44". Any ideas?

Comment: I've added it to NuGet and also shared the source code for easier contributions: https://github.com/SourceCodeBackup/GenCode128